# Is it possible to encode different blocks using different huffman codes(fixed and dynamic) in deflate algorithm?

Tags: huffman-code, deflate

Is it possible to encode different data blocks in a file using different huffman codes (some blocks using fixed and some using dynamic)? If so, how can deflate decompress detects these different blocks?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Each deflate block starts with a three-bit header indicating whether this is the last block or not (one bit), and which of three possible block types it is (two bits).

Comment: Thanks Mark for quick response.